# NoClassDefFoundError on Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mapsforge

I have this problem that i can't understand how to solve. i have imported a maps forge project in eclipse using maven, but if try to load the project on device, i get this error.
But i know that that class is in the project. How can i solve this problem?

I am working with the Mapsforge rescue 4.0 library.
I have used the same method to import Mapsforge 0.31 and everything works fine.

```
    02-25 16:46:03.202: E/AndroidRuntime(6370): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.mapsforge.map.android.graphics.AndroidGraphicFactory
```

This is the pom.xml of the app.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.mapsforge
        mapsforge
        0.4.0-SNAPSHOT
        ../../../pom.xml

```
<artifactId>Samples</artifactId>
<packaging>apk</packaging>

<properties>
    <rootDirectory>../../../</rootDirectory>
    <targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <dex>
                    <jvmArguments>
                        <jvmArgument>-Xmx512M</jvmArgument>
                    </jvmArguments>
                </dex>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
                <buildOutputDirectory>bin/classes</buildOutputDirectory>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder</buildcommand>
                    <buildcommand>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder</buildcommand>
                    <buildcommand>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder</buildcommand>
                    <buildcommand>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <classpathContainers>
                    <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                    <classpathContainer>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK</classpathContainer>
                    <classpathContainer>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES</classpathContainer>
                    <classpathContainer>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES</classpathContainer>
                </classpathContainers>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>com.google.android:android</exclude>
                    <exclude>org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient</exclude>
                    <exclude>org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore</exclude>
                    <exclude>commons-codec:commons-codec</exclude>
                    <exclude>commons-logging:commons-logging</exclude>
                    <exclude>org.json:json</exclude>
                    <exclude>org.khronos:opengl-api</exclude>
                    <exclude>xerces:xmlParserAPIs</exclude>
                    <exclude>xpp3:xpp3</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapsforge</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapsforge-map-android</artifactId>
        <type>apklib</type>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.2_r2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.android.robotium</groupId>
        <artifactId>robotium-solo</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
        <version>r7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: are u using project as Library??

Comment: It's seems like `org.mapsforge.map.android.graphics.AndroidGraphicFactory` class not available

Comment: sorry, i haven' explained myself clear. Mapsforge include a Sample app that you can run in your device to see how it works. the previous version had the same feature which never gave me problem. Ut i cannot start this application because of this problem

Comment: are you importing mapsforge-map-android? that's where this class is defined. You should post your maven dependencies definition.

Comment: for what i see, mapsforge-map-android is in the folder target/unpacked-libs/org.mapsforge_mapsforge-map-android_apklib_0.4.0-SNAPSHOT/src

Comment: you mean the pom.properties in the maven-archiver folder?

Comment: anybody can help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows:

1. Download those 5 files:
   mapsforge-core
   mapsforge-map
   mapsforge-map-reader
   mapsforge-map-android
   svg-android
2. Put those libraries (jar files) in your project folder **libs**
3. Than go to Project->clean

You don't need to install Maven or other plugins. Including the libraries through Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs won't work. You need to put it in the libs folder.
If it still doesn't work, make sure you update your android tools and try again.

Good luck :)