# NoClassDefFoundError with Mapsforge 0.5.0 and Eclipse, cannot build

Tags: android, eclipse, mapsforge

I am trying to add a map view to my application using Mapsforge. I have done the following:

Downloaded jar files and placed them in the libs/ folder

mapsforge-core-0.5.0.jar --- mapsforge-map-0.5.0.jar --- mapsforge-map-android-0.5.0.jar --- mapsforge-map-reader-0.5.0.jar

I face this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.mapsforge.map.android.graphics.AndroidGraphicFactory
```

At this line:

```
AndroidGraphicFactory.createInstance(this.getApplication());
```

[I am trying to do this tutorial](http://mapsforge.org/docs/dev/md_docs_Getting-Started-Android-App.html)

it long 2 days I am trying but can't solve my problem.
I saw [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587939/noclassdeffounderror-with-mapsforge-0-4-0-and-eclipse) and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019896/noclassdeffounderror-on-android-project) and [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049291/noclassdeffounderror-with-mapsforge-0-4-0-and-eclipse-cannot-build) but none helped me :(
any one can help me?

Comment: Is each jar visible in Private Dependencies tree? Make use each jar's icon shows an overlay under libs folder. If not, add it to Build Path.

Comment: tnx for reply . I right clicked on all jars in libs and add them to build path but the problem persist.by the way jars are listed in Libraries tab and order and export tab of java build path dialog

Comment: What is your current target JRE environment in Eclipse Java preferences ? It should be either jre 7 or jdk 7. It seems like mapsforge jars have been compiled in java 7

Comment: it shows jre8 in preferences-java-installed JREs

Comment: Try download jdk 7 and set it as target to avoid problem with java 8

Comment: Or try to re-compile mapsforge github by yourself

Comment: jre7 does not helped either :( but I dont know how to recompile mapsforge github

Comment: the reason I am trying mapsforge 0.5 is that I have a project with old mapsforge version that force close on some devices with this error:   'java.lang.NullPointerException
  at org.mapsforge.map.reader.MapDatabase.executeQuery(MapDatabase.java:251)
 at org.mapsforge.android.maps.mapgenerator.databaserenderer.DatabaseRenderer.executeJob(DatabaseRenderer.java:169)
 at org.mapsforge.android.maps.mapgenerator.MapWorker.doWork(MapWorker.java:73)
  at org.mapsforge.android.maps.PausableThread.run(PausableThread.java:94)
'   do you know how to fix it?